# Install firebirdsql 2.1 super without dpkg-reconfigure on ubuntu 10.04.3?

Tags: ubuntu, firebird, chef-solo

I try to install firebird2.1-super with chef. So I can't use `dpkg-reconfigure`. 
So I tried to use

```
debconf-set-selections /var/cache/firebird/firebird-server.seed
```

In firebird-server.seed:

```
firebird2.1-super       shared/firebird/sysdba_password/first_install  
                                                           password  qwerty 

firebird2.1-super       shared/firebird/server_in_use   error
firebird2.1-super       shared/firebird/purge_databases boolean false
firebird2.1-super       shared/firebird/enabled boolean true
firebird2.1-super       shared/firebird/purge_security  boolean false
```

But this change nothing. After install (`sudo apt-get install firebird2.1-super`) firebird didn't start up automatically.

What can I do to start firebird automatically without `dpkg-reconfigure`? How to preseed firebird in the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Found this one:

> For future reference if someone else encounters this problem. If you
>   edit /etc/default/firebird2.5 so that the ENABLE_FIREBIRD_SERVER
>   variable is set to TRUE. Then you can just run sudo service
>   firebird2.5-super start to run the service without having to
>   reconfigure the package. This however assumes that you've taken care
>   of creating the password file and related configuration options.